# Workarounds for a global / local naming conflicts

Tags: scala, scala-3

Say I have these two classes:

```
class A {
  def foo(i: String) = println(s"${i}")
  def foo(i: String, j: Int) = println(s"${i} ${j}")
}

class B {
  def foo(i: Int) = println(s"${i}")
  def foo(i: Int, j: String) = println(s"${i} ${j}")
}
```

I have the variable with the same name as a global variable and as a method in a class:

```
val inst = A()

abstract class AppB extends App { 
  def inst = B()
}
```

I extend the above:

```
object MyApp extends AppB {
  // Should reference A
  inst.foo("s11")
  inst.foo("s22", 11)
  
  // Should reference B
  inst.foo(33)
  inst.foo(44, "s33")
}
```

Assuming I do not want to rename, is there a way to:

- Reference the global `val inst`?
- "Shadow" `def inst` somehow, so that I can only use the global `val inst` one?

Comment: I suppose this is Scala 2, right?

Comment: @GaëlJ Scala 3.

Comment: @GaëlJ So in the second code block there's a `val inst = A()`. Assume this is all in the same file as written, without the text I added to break it up to hopefully explain things :)

Comment: It depends of the real case (I assume this one is simplified) but maybe this can be a use case for `export` feature. Otherwise, global definitions might be accessible with the auto "generated" package name maybe? https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/package-objects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/package-objects.html:

> If a source file `src.scala` contains such top-level definitions, they will be put in a synthetic object named `src$package`

Maybe using the "auto-generated" `object` name to access `val inst` can work in this case?

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked for the first question! Any ideas about the 2nd question?

Comment: If you need/want to keep inheritance, I don't see a way to shadow the method. If using composition instead, it seems a good use case for the new Export Clause feature: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/export.html